# I need to review changes of a table before save them

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I got problem with my database, I need to review a suggested changes made by a user to a business, my idea was to have the same structure of my table business and store inside that table the changes suggested and then review the changes and update my row on the original table of business, but I think this is not a good idea. How could I design my database without repeting that table structure?

Comment: Existing system or new system?  "WORK" tables (similar table structures) are one accepted way and records flow out of work tables into final tables when approved.  Another approach is to use a status on the record and status controls flow.  There's risk with a status approach in that developers may already have structures in place that don't look at status.  But if you have control over the data though API that can be mitigated easily enough. or if this is a new system then the status concept can be in place.  however status has risks as well if you need to retain the current state until appvd

Comment: we are building a new system and we need to retain the data until somebody approve the changes to the record, as you said I think the first option is the best way

Comment: Given new system, and a need to retain current record... I'd likely create a copy of the base table and call the "pending approval" table a SameTable_work or SameTable_WF for (workflow) incase there are multiple changes needing approval for the same record.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).